# Rails delete link url took wrong page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I delete a post, it takes me to `post/index.html.erb`, but I want it to redirect to the `profile/index.html.erb` page.

```
<% current_user.posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.post_name %> </p>
  <%= link_to "view", post, class: "btn btn-default" %>
  <%= link_to "Delete", post_path(post), method: :delete,    
                                         data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, 
                                         class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong code. Your view has nothing to do with this. Fix/change the redirection in your `PostsController#destroy`.